# reference request: Borel measure is Gaussian iff Fourier transform involves positive definite bilinear form

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, fourier-transform, topological-vector-spaces

I am looking for a reference of the following theorem

> A Borel probability measure $\mu$ on a topological vector space $X$ is centered Gaussian if and only if there exists a positive semidefinite symmetric bilinear form $q: X^{\ast} \times X^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
> $$ \int_X \exp(i f(x)) ~ d \mu(x) = \exp(- \frac{1}{2} ~q(f,f))$$

One direction can be shown as follows:

Assume $\mu$ is Gaussian, then by definition every $f \in X^{\ast}$ is a Gaussian random variable $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Hence

\begin{equation}
\int_X e^{if(x)} d \mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{iy} d \underbrace{f_{\ast}\mu(y)}_{\sim N(0, \text{Var}(f))} = \varphi_f(1) = \exp(- \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(f))
\end{equation}

In finite dimension, the other dimension is done via Fourier inversion, but I am not sure about the infinite case.

Comment: See Theorem 2.2.4. on page 43 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=UtufBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&dq=bogachev+gaussian+measures+2.2.4.+Theorem&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNiszY3qjvAhWEIMUKHbc8DCgQ6AEwAHoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=bogachev%20gaussian%20measures%202.2.4.%20Theorem&f=false).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Please post it as an answer, then I can accept it.